# favorite button is appearing as word instead of heart using materialize

Tags: css, materialize

I am learning web using materialize and I am trying to create favorite button which has heart on it but when I am using materialize it show the word "favorite" instead of the heart

here is my code `<div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title">Blueberries & coconut smoothie</span>
                    <a href="" class="favorite-btn btn-floating pink pulse">
                        <i class="material-icons">favorite</i>
                    </a>
                </div>`

and here is screenshot for what I got

[image: css]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must include the material-icons google fonts CDN for it to work.

```
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

paste the above tag in the `<head>` tag of your index.html and it should work fine,
also refer [materialize docs for icons](https://materializecss.com/icons.html)